# Optical character recognition plugins for Ionic Framework

Tags: image, ionic-framework, text, extract

Is there any option of optical character recognition plugins for Ionic Framework , watched a few videos concerning OCR implementation in you tube for extracting text from the images clicked or videos captured and tried in your application ,but problem arrived is regarding time.Its taking to much time parse data from the image , plugin we are using is google tesseract and abbyy ocr plugins. Looking for better plugin or standard to extract the text in minimal time may in 5 seconds and accurate text .

Plugin Name : cordova-plugin-tesseract -ocr

Comment: Please watch video tutorial for same.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIzZe8irmRs

Comment: That is made using latest version of ionic 4